# What is TDLib of telegram and why do we still need all kind languages client for it, Q: How can we send Photo with TDLib?

Tags: javascript, nodes, telegram

According to telegram.org, Telegram Database Library (TDLib) is "TDLib (Telegram Database Library) is a cross-platform, fully functional Telegram client. We designed it to help third-party developers create their own custom apps using the Telegram platform."
Source code is available on (https://github.com/tdlib/td).
While I am trying to write some auto replay for my telegram account with JavaScript.  Found  (https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl) which is what suites the purpose of learning JavaScript.

Sending text with Bannerets/tdl is well documented (and it is much easy to understand comparing to https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/), but sending media like photo and voice seem is not available from Bannerets/tdl

As a new coder, wonder https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl has the capability to send [messagePhoto](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1message_photo.html) as TDLib,
if so, how can we use it?
if not, how can we use https://github.com/tdlib/td to send photo with python code as an example?

Would like to know the differences of TDLib vs other languages of "TDLib". And for those other languages available TDLib on github are completed, which make those "TDLib" functional as the TDlib from the official website.
if not, how can we use the TDLib from the official website to send photo.

Answer (score 0):

to send the photos you use the same call as you [see on examples](https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl/blob/d020d16d4e67238038ee5f164c2bcb3660701b6f/examples/send-message.js#L16-L20).

Roughly, it would be something like this:

```js
  await client.invoke({
    _: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id: 123456789,
    input_message_content: {
      _: 'inputMessagePhoto',
      photo: {
        _: 'inputFile',
        path: '/path/to/your/photo/my-photo.jpg'
      }
    }
  })
```

Note that the syntax or parameters may be slightly wrong, you better check on the tdlib docs https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1send_message.html you will see that `sendMessage` is a class and the fields all match with the call in javascript.
For example, input_message_content would lead [here](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1send_message.html#a1c458c7b79b78de075300304a851a55d) and if you clock on the class `InputMessageContent`, it should lead you to [its definition](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1_input_message_content.html).

The idea here is that you navigate on the structure to see what are the parameters and, you will see that `inputMessagePhoto` is also a class which has the `photo` field, which is an `inputFile` class and so forth.

About the other languages for tdlib, they are just wrappers around the original library to bring that native flavor of the language you are using, be it python or nodejs.

In the end, they will call the same code but should be easier for you to implement a client without having to call the original c++ library.